# How to check if some nested method has caused exception and it is handled?

Tags: c#

I am having a code like -

```
void OuterMethod()
{
    InnerMethod();
    //Some way to know that InnerMethod() have some handled exception.
}

void InnerMethod()
{
    try
    {
        //Some Exception Thrown.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception Handled.
    }
}
```

Now, When I am calling InnerMethod() there is an Handled Exception in it. Problem is that I need to know it at OuterMethod() too where I am calling InnerMethod().

P.S. - I can not change the return type as its a huge already written code with many nested method. And method is used as many refrences.

Comment: Maybe [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) _could_ help? (E.g. by using [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/))

Comment: After all, it looks to me like this is exactly the way _not_ to use exceptions.

Comment: Remove the catch block from the inner method... Either you handle it or you don't. A re-throw is also OK.

Comment: *Why* do you need to know about the exception? Presumably, the reason why it was handled was precisely because it was decided that *it can be handled, so no need to bother calling code with it*. Have you considered simply rethrowing it in that `catch`-block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw it again in an inner method, and catch in an outer

```
void OuterMethod()
{
    try
    {
        InnerMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception Handled.
    }
}

void InnerMethod()
{
    try
    {
        //Some Exception Thrown.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception Handled.
        //some logic
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
void OuterMethod()
{
    try
    {
        InnerMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}

void InnerMethod()
{
    //if exception occurs, throw
}
```